# How to get reference to UITextField *that is on the screen* from tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I'm adding subview (UITableView with delegate from a different file) and I want to change UITextField's text when a row is selected.

The text field is in AddViewController:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemName;
```

I create the table in AddViewController:

```
AddViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    autocompleteDelegate = [[AutocompleteTable alloc] init];
    ...
    autocompleteTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, 320, 120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    autocompleteTable.delegate = (id)autocompleteDelegate;
    autocompleteTable.dataSource = (id)autocompleteDelegate;
    ...
    [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTable];
}
```

How to change the UITextField's text from here?

```
AutocompleteTable.m

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    itemName.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text; //something like this

    self.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.itemName.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
```

Make sure also that your IBOutlet is connected with the TextView in storyboard.

Comment: This wont work, because the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is in AutocompleteTable.m but the itemName is in AddViewController.m: Property 'itemName' not found on object of type 'AutocompleteTable *'

Comment: Then you need to set up protocol and set AddViewController as AutoCompleteTable's delegate to get notified when AutoCompleteTable is selected...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm